# Error after creating static library in xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I have created a static library for iOS with Xcode 4.2 and added UIKit framework, but while building the library, I am getting an error message for UIImage class and UIWebDelegate:

> Parse Issue Expected type

Please suggest me how to use UIKit framework in xcode 4.2 in static library.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`.